# Creating CSV file using apache camel spring

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to create csv file from camel spring but getting error.Following is the code I have developed-

```
    <from uri="quartz2://myqyartz?cron=cronexpr"/>
    <to uri="bean:TestProcessor" />
    <marshal>
    <csv> 
    <header>orderId</header>
    <header>amount</header>
    <header>amount2</header>
    <header>amount3</header>
    <header>amount4</header>
    </csv>
    </marshal>
    <to uri="file:/home/user/Terminal?fileName=abc.csv"/>
    </route>
```

I have also tried to use `<convertBodyTo type="java.util.List"/>` but it is giving me exception as

> No type converter available to convert from type:
>   com.test.TestBean to the required type: java.util.List with
>   value
>   com.test.TestBean@26cd85e5[name=test,tumber=500,batchId=122,Type=XYZ,c_count=25,Count=14,amount=555]

Here TestBean is my POJO and I'm returning java.util.list of TestBean objects from bean:TestProcessor. Will camel automatically link object's properties with header or do I need to write separate processor class for type conversion,if yes then how to convert java.util.list to required format in it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: explain not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a "marshall" step in your route.

```
<from uri="quartz2://myqyartz?cron=cronexpr"/>
  <transform>
    <simple>this will be file content</simple>
  </transform>
  <process ref="bodyToListProcessor"/>
  <marshal>
    <csv />
  </marshal>
<to uri="file:/home/user/?fileName=abc.csv"/>

<bean id="bodyToListProcessor" class="own.package.MyProcessor"/>
```

You can find more information here http://camel.apache.org/csv.html and here: http://camel.apache.org/processor.html

**Edit**

To be able to insert your POJO model as CSV entries, you can use "camel-bindy".
With this component you can bind CSV data format to one or many POJOs.

For example:

```
<dataFormats>
  <bindy id="bindyDataformat" type="Csv" classType="org.apache.camel.bindy.model.Order"/>
</dataFormats>

<route>
  <from uri="quartz2://myqyartz?cron=cronexpr" />
  <marshal ref="bindyDataformat" />
  <to uri="file:/home/user/?fileName=abc.csv" />
</route>
```

Please, check the following link for more information: http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html

Comment: Thanks.I have added that code but I'm getting this exception -  No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.util.List with value this will be file content.Any idea?

Comment: I see. The problem is that Camel is expecting a List before the "marshal" step. Maybe you can try to add a processor to "process" the body message to a List.

Comment: Thanks again for your edit.I have updated question now.Could you please help me in it?I have checked with List<List<String>> and its working fine,so is there any way to make it working for List<CustomBeanObjects>?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the answer with a mention to "camel-bindy".

Comment: Thanks for your help I'll check it.